# finding files on linux in non hidden directory

Tags: linux, unix, find, command

In the following command i want to search only only the directories which are non hidden how can i do this using the following command .Iwant to ignore hidden directories while searching the log file

```
  find /home/tom/project/ -name '.log.txt'
```

Output:

```
    /home/tom/project/.log.txt
    /home/tom/project1/.log.txt

     find: Filesystem loop detected; ./.snapshot/hourly.0' has the same device number and inode as a directory which is 2 levels higher in the filesystem hierarchy. 
     find: Filesystem loop detected; ./.snapshot/hourly.1' has the same device number and inode as a directory which is 2 levels higher in the filesystem hierarchy.
```

I want eliminate all the find messages or do not serach in the hidden directory

```
  ls /home/tom/project/  
  dir1   
  dir2  
 .backup 
 .snapshot/
 .ignore/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to ignore the error messages then redirect stdout to a file or /dev/null

```
find /home/tom/project/ -name '.log.txt' 2>/dev/null
```

If you may be interested in other error messages but not the particular ones you mention in your question then pipe the output through grep -v

```
find /home/tom/project/ -name '.log.txt' | grep -v 'Filesystem loop detected'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
     `find . -name '.log.txt' ! -wholename ".*.*/.log.txt"`

Find all files with name = .log.txt, but also make sure file full path does not contain more than one DOT in the folder section. First dot is current directory.

If instead of current directory, an absolute path is provided, use following command
`find . -name '.log.txt' ! -wholename "*.*/.log.txt"`

Comment: General logic is centered around detection of hidden folders in unix. Hidden folder starts with a DOT.

Comment: The output is still ther same cannot surpass the snapshot directory

Comment: The `find` command will still check all sub directorys, but it will show in output only the ones with correct match. It seems taht Iain's answer could help you in that regard. Note, I don't understand why is that error shown, since `find` ,by default, does not follow any links.